Using MEXC API with Python
I am making a trading bot using mexc API in Python but I am getting this error:

{'code': 700002, 'msg': 'Signature for this request is not valid.'}

# Signature creation function

def create_signature(secret_key, params):
# Sorting the parameters

query_string = '&'.join([f"{key}={value}" for key, value in sorted(params.items())])
# Creating the HMAC SHA256 signature

signature = hmac.new(secret_key.encode('utf-8'), query_string.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
return signature`

# Adding the signature to the parameters

params['signature'] = create_signature(API_SECRET, params)

headers = { 
X-MEXC-APIKEY': API_KEY }` `# Send request response = requests.post(BASE_URL + endpoint, params=params, headers=headers) return response.json()

What is solution of the error?

your code has too many errors and cannot run. please correct it
